# Ansible - start tomcat on host

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I've been working on ansible playbook to download and start tomcat in a host.

This is my inventory host file:

```
[group1]
machine1 ansible_host=10.40.0.168
```

I have group1.yml file in my group_vars:

```
---
ansible_ssh_user: user
ansible_ssh_pass: pass
ansible_sudo_pass: passp
```

My playbook is:

```
---
- hosts: group1
  sudo: yes
  tasks:

 - name: Update all packages to the latest version
   apt:
     upgrade: dist

- name: Download tomcat
  get_url: url=http://mirrors.up.pt/pub/apache/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.1/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.1-fulldocs.tar.gz dest=/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.1.tar.gz

- name: Unarchive a file that is already on the remote machine
  unarchive:
   src: /opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.1.tar.gz
   dest: /opt/
   remote_src: yes

- name: Run Tomcat
  shell: ./startup.sh
  args:
    chdir: /opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.1/bin
```

I try to run `./startup.sh` in `/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.1/bin` folder to start tomcat.

I run the following command:

```
ansible-playbook playbookname.yml
```

If I run `./startup.sh` in a host machine it works fine, but when I run it from the control machine I get:

```
PLAY [group1] **********************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************
ok: [myname]

TASK [Update all packages to the latest version] ***********************************************************************
ok: [myname]

TASK [Download tomcat] *************************************************************************************************
ok: [myname]

TASK [Unarchive a file that is already on the remote machine] **********************************************************
ok: [myname]

TASK [Run Tomcat] ******************************************************************************************************
changed: [myname]

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************
myname                       : ok=5    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

After this I try to open tomcat, but it's not running on the host.

How can I start tomcat from ansible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should add it as a service, eg as below:

service file: /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service (It should be in target destination machine)

File should contain as below, (Adjust to your java environment)

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk/jre
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.47/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.47
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.47
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC'
Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom'

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.47/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/bin/kill -15 $MAINPID

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then start the server with below systemd ansible module,

```
- name: enable tomcat startup
    systemd:
    name: tomcat
    enabled: yes
    state: restarted
    become: true
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use system tools for that, like Systemd etc. depending on your OS.
Ansible should only create the service file and start the service. Running the servie is not the job of Ansible.

Possible way to do that: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-centos-7#install-tomcat